# "If only you would just sign the register, "He said to me

Tags: reported-speech

"If only you would just sign the register, "He said to me. 
How can I narrate it indirectly? 
How to change it into indirect?

Comment: Something like, "*He told me about his utter disappointment of my not signing the register.*" maybe.  What exactly do you wish to emphasize?

Answer (score 2):

You might try "ask"/"plead" or one of their synonyms . . . .

"He asked me to sign the register."

"He pleaded with me to sign the register."

"He begged me to sign the register."

Or, if it fits, "he tried to get me to sign the register."